# How to distribute my own ios .framework file through cocoapods?

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I developed my own .framework that contains a static library and a bundled resource. I would like to distribute it through cocoapods. Is this possible? If so, what do I have to do?

Comment: Hi @iamarnold, did you manage to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)

If you want to have you own pod, you can do that as private pod. Please ignore it if am giving in different direction

To distribute compiled framework:

I don't think you could directly distribute the compiled framework, but i think you do it other way.

1. First compile your existing framework, expose whatever functions you want as public and compile.
2. Create another new framework and import your existing compiled framework and create a wrapper class to access the public function in the new framework.So your private functions are safe.
3. Distribute the new framework as private pod, Whoever want to use could compile and use the new framework which will have access to the public functions of the  existing one(wrapper class functions - which is coupled with old framework functions) and again your private functions are safe.

Note : I didn't try this. Check whether it works or not. Please share your knowledge after testing this and sorry if it is not working out.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it's not exactly what I wanted. I'm trying to distribute a compiled framework file through cocoapods.

Comment: Check my edited answer and again sry if am deviating.